# Accessing Nested Objects in JavaScript where inner objects have serial numbers as labels

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script

I have a nested object where the inner objects have random serial numbers as their labels.

If I have data like this:

```
const user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'Jack',
        address: {
            line1: 'westwish st',
            line2: 'washmasher',
            city: 'wallas',
            state: 'WX'
        }
    }
}
```

I can access the inner object with

```
const name = user.personalInfo.name;
const userCity = user.personalInfo.address.city;
```

But my inner objects have random serial numbers, not static labels like `address` as in the above example.

```
{
    "id": "48121be5c6b55ae23928316f5",
    "component": "select",
    "customFields": [

    ],
    "index": 0,
    "label": "Select",
    "description": null,
    "placeholder": null,
    "editable": true,
    "options": {
      "f1c7363b085cd671a59": {
        "index": 0,
        "value": "AA",
        "label": "A"
      },
      "3d8508fb86c6af84637": {
        "index": 1,
        "value": "BB",
        "label": "B"
      },
      "615b8ba2c0b7e88b8b5": {
        "index": 2,
        "value": "DD",
        "label": "D"
      }
    },
    "required": false,
    "validation": "/.*/",
    "imported": false
  }
```

How do I access the `value` for each inner object of the `options` object?

Comment: Search: Iterate a js object. `Object.values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.keys() to iterate through the properties of the "options" object like this:

```
const optionKeys = Object.keys(data.options);
optionKeys.forEach(key => {
    const innerObject = data.options[key];
    console.log(innerObject.value); // Access the "value" property of each inner object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the inner objects' data within the "options" object,
you can use **[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)** method to iterate through the keys and access their respective data.

please check below code example:

```js
  const productDetails = {
  "id": "48121be5c6b55ae23928316f5",
  "products": {
    "b14ea0b7ed094618a341424a": {
      "index": 0,
      "value": "AA",
      "label": "A"
    },
    "3958b0085dcf4bde9e0bf8f15": {
      "index": 1,
      "value": "BB",
      "label": "B"
    },
    "6b38bd4df2aa438caf0e85b7": {
      "index": 2,
      "value": "DD",
      "label": "D"
    },
    //...more objects
  }
};

const productKeys = Object.keys(productDetails.products);

for (const key of productKeys) {
  const innerObject = productDetails.products[key];
  console.log(`Key: ${key}`);
  console.log(`Value: ${innerObject.value}`);
}
```